# PHP Silex routing localization

Tags: php, routes, locale, silex

starting with Silex.

Say I want a localised site where all routes have to start with `/{_locale}` and don't fancy repeating myself as :

```
$app->match('/{_locale}/foo', function() use ($app) {
return $app['twig']->render('foo.twig');
})
->assert('_locale', implode('|', $app['languages.available']))
->value('_locale', $app['locale.default'])
->bind('foo');

$app->match('/{_locale}/bar', function() use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('bar.twig');
    })
    ->assert('_locale', implode('|', $app['languages.available']))
    ->value('_locale', $app['locale.default'])
    ->bind('bar');
```

Ideally, I'd like to create a base route that would match the locale and subclass it in some way but couldn't figure out by myself how to trigger that in an elegant way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can delegate the local detection with `mount` function:

You mount a route for each local you want to support, but they redirect to the same controller:

```
    $app->mount('/en/', new MyControllerProvider('en'));
    $app->mount('/fr/', new MyControllerProvider('fr'));
    $app->mount('/de/', new MyControllerProvider('de'));
```

And now the local can be an attribute of your controller:

```
class MyControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface {

    private $_locale;

    public function __construct($_locale) {
        $this->_locale = $_locale;
    }

    public function connect(Application $app) {
        $controler = $app['controllers_factory'];


        $controler->match('/foo', function() use ($app) {
                            return $app['twig']->render('foo.twig');
                        })
                ->bind('foo');

        $controler->match('/bar', function() use ($app) {
                            return $app['twig']->render('bar.twig');
                        })
                ->bind('bar');

        return $controler;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes ! That would do. Thank you !