# Language routing in Silex

Tags: php, routes, silex

I'm looking for a solution where I can routing in Silex different URLs to a controller to get more organized my code.

The problem is that I need to route to the same controllerProvider some routes in different languages:

`$app->mount("/{_locale}/string-in-english", new App\Controllers\myController());`

`$app->mount("/{_locale}/string-in-spanish", new App\Controllers\ myController());`

Where /string-in-english and /string-in-spanish are routed to the same controller.

Most likely, the possible routes are inserted into a table in a database.

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673037/php-silex-routing-localization) which is not very different that yours.

Answer (score 0):

Full i18n routing is tricky, you will need to use a translation service and a single call to a mount() that can handle translatable routes.

Take a look to [this article](http://dev.umpirsky.com/silex-i18n-routing/). There are some interesting comments and the author published an [I18nRoutingServiceProvider](https://github.com/umpirsky/I18nRoutingServiceProvider).

In my opinion Silex rocks when used in simple apps, but it can become really hard when you start to add this kind of features. Sometimes it is easier to implement them in a Symfony app.